# Self registering Classes

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am currently starting developing an Alexa Skill in C#. As I did not want to have a messy if block checking the intent type of an incoming request I got the following idea:
Writing a static class *RequestHandler* which stores a list of all possible intents (List of *IIntent* interface which will be implemented by classes which represent an intent).

I know have the conceptional problem, that I do not know what the best way to register those intents might be. My first idea was to just write

```
internal static void RegisterIntent(IIntent intent) => Intents.Add(intent);
```

and call this in static constructors of each intent. At this point I didn´t know static constructors only will be executed the first time the class will be accessed. So this idea is not working as I thought. 
The other ideas I for know can think of, are:

- adding a static Initialize / Register method to each intent class in which it creates an instance which will be added into the static intent list --> this will result in a lot of initiliaze methods I would have to add manually to the executed lambda function.
- adding an Initialize method to the static RequestHandler which will add an instance of each intent class to the static list --> I still would have to manually write the *RegisterIntent(new ABCIntent())* command for each intent class.

Is there a way to get all intent classes be added into the static list without adding code for this register action manually? Or are there better ways to achieve this than those two ones I had so far? Maybe with reflection (tbh: I am quite new to AWS lamda development and I do not know if this will work).

Comment: You should be looking at dependency injection frameworks like StructureMap, AutoFac, Unity and so on, because they are built for situations like this. If for example all of your intents implements a certain interface like IIntent and all concrete implementations of intents implement this interface then the dependency injection framework can automatically register them and give you a list of them.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. But I feel like using a full framework is a bit too much for me right now as I am still only experimenting with Alexa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meanwhile changed the registration using reflection. So I can search for all classes implementing the `IIntent` interface in the static constructor of the request handler.

```
    static RequestHandler()
    {
        var assembly = typeof(RequestHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        foreach (var t in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IIntent)))
            {
                Intents.Add(Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Or are there any better proposals?